# How to set sysdba password in Oracle 11G

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-connection, sqlplus

I tried to connect to database using sqlplus using below command :

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

I have used the same password that I had set while creating database and setting password for sys and sysdba. But it shows below error :

> ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

How to connect to the database?

I have installed Oracle DB in local PC with Windows 10 as Operating System and administrator privileges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Log on to your Windows server as a member of the Administrators group or a member of the ORA_DBA group. 
Try the below steps

```
sqlplus /nolog
connect / as sysdba
Once connected, you can change the SYS password to something you know: 
ALTER USER sys IDENTIFIED BY new_password;
```

Comment: Windows server means IIS?

Comment: no, windows server means windows 2003-8-12 server which has a `cmd.exe` (command line tool) to execute the above. Also an windows server can "run" the oracle database as a process. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server for further info. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter : how to find windows server and its respective cmd.exe

Comment: It could be one of a dozen different ways. Easiest to ask someone familiar with your local computing environment. Do you have co-workers,  a manager, sys-admins or (worst case) and IT help desk?  Work your way up thru that list. Else write a new question "How do I find the windows server that is running my oracle database"? Try to include more detail about what you **have** figured out. Given what you have posted above are too many possibilities. Good luck.

Comment: most easiest way is to find another user colleague maybe with SYSDBA privileges. That user will be able to re-set the SYS password.

Comment: @NitinTripathi : I have installed it in local PC and having this issue